# How to create a web3.js provider with chainID?

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs

I want to create a web3 provider on a Node.js application with a specific chainID and URL. How can I do it?

```
    const chains: Chain[] = await this.chainRepository.find({
      relations: ['currencies'],
    });

    const providers = chains.map((chain) => {
      return new Web3(chain.chainRpc);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to chainlist.org/chain/{chain-id}
    e.g. [chainlist.org/chain/56](https://chainlist.org/chain/56) for BNB
Copy the first link under *RPC Server Address*
Get Web3 object as followin

```
return new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(past-copied-url-here));
```